# In SharePoint 2010 how do I see My Visual WebPart Feature in site features

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am setting up a new website in Sharepoint 2010 and I will be using webparts for this site.

When I am going to the `Site settings -> Site features` my feature is not showing so I am not able to activate it. Any idea what I need to do to see it and activate it in the site features?

Comment: If you can provide a screen capture than it it better to understand

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't really specific, so I am posting some basic ideas that may help you finding out the real root of the problem.

- I assume that we are talking about a custom web part and feature. Is the solution already installed on your environment? You should be able to check this from the central administration site, confirm that under the Farm Solutions page the solution is available and deployed.
- Web Parts usually are deployed thru features scoped at **site collection** level, not just web site. If that is the case, you should be checking `Site Settings -> Site Collection Features` instead, since `Site Features` only include web scoped features. As a warning, note that the the "Site Collection Features" option is only available on the "Site Setting" page for *the root site of the site collection*.
- If the feature is still missing, check that whoever created the solution package didn't mark it as hidden by mistake. This would hide it from the user interface, making activation only possible by code/scripts. In this case, you can use a tool like SharePoint Manager to check if the feature is indeed there, but the tool could be a little confusing if you aren't used to SharePoint object model structure.
- If anything else fails and you just deployed the feature, IISRESET is worth a try. Also, should you be in a multi-machine farm environment, with multiple application server and web front ends it is worth checking if all the solution files have been propagated correctly across the farm. Special attention should be given at the SharePoint root folder `/Features` subfolder: I have seen multiple "missing feature" in the past begin caused by missing files on a server machine due to some hanged/upstarted deploy service.

To start, I would check these basic pointers. If none helps, try to update your question with further info and I will try to see what comes to mind.